# Splitting string before name of month with regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, replace, data-cleaning

I have a bunch of lines with random text, and at the end of each line, a timestamp. I am trying to split these lines right before the timestamp.

Current output:

```
Yes, I'd say so. Nov 08, 2014 UTC
Hell yes! Oct 01, 2014 UTC 
Anbefalt som bare det, løp og kjøp. Sep 16, 2014 UTC
Etc.
```

Desired output (by "tab" I mean the actual whitespace):

```
Yes, I'd say so. <tab> Nov 08, 2014 UTC
Hell yes! <tab> Oct 01, 2014 UTC
Anbefalt som bare det, løp og kjøp. <tab> Sep 16, 2014 UTC
Etc.
```

So far I have used "replace" to place a tab character right before the month. Like this:

```
my_string.replace("May ", "\tMay ").replace("Apr ", "\tApr ").replace("Mar ", "\tMar ").replace("Feb ", "\tFeb ") etc. (incomplete code)
```

This works fairly well, except when the random text involves the name of a month, e.g. "I bought it last may, great stuff". As the date is formatted in such a specific way I'd like to improve on this with regex and wildcards, if possible. Is there a way to place a tab before these dates? As you can see above, the dates are formatted as follows:

```
[Three-letter abbreviation of the month] [two-digit day] [,] [four-digit year] [UTC]
```

E.g.

```
Oct 31, 2014 UTC
```

Pardon the amateurish code and approach, I am an absolute regex n00b. I have looked around for answers here on SO, but I've come short. I hope someone can help!

Comment: Everyone always wants to use regexes! There are often simpler solutions for string manipulation, as shown by the solutions below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a one RegeEx for all months:

```
import re

lines = [
    "Yes, I'd say so. Nov 08, 2014 UTC",
    "Hell yes! Oct 01, 2014 UTC"
]

for ln in lines:
    print re.sub(r'(\w+\s\d{2}, \d{4} UTC)$', r'\t\1', ln)
```

Which will return:

```
Yes, I'd say so.    Nov 08, 2014 UTC
Hell yes!   Oct 01, 2014 UTC
```

How it works is simple. `re.sub` captures everything in the parentheses of the first argument and assigns it to `\1`. The second argument `r'\t\1'` is what we want to replace the string with.

In your case you want to replace it with the original string (represented by `\1`) with a tab character (`\t`) in front of it.

Answer (score 2):

If you can always guarantee it's that many words, then you don't need a regex, just reverse split and join using builtin functions, eg:

```
s = "Yes, I'd say so. Nov 08, 2014 UTC"
split = s.rsplit(None, 4)
new = split[0] + '\t' + ' '.join(split[1:])
# "Yes, I'd say so.\tNov 08, 2014 UTC"
```

Comment: Interesting, what does the 4 refer to?

Comment: @user3343907 it's the maximum numbers of splits to do - so in this case, just split on 4 whitespace characters, then stop, that leaves the first item of the list with your text, and the rest we re-join with spaces to reconstruct... much faster and efficient than using a regex (building a finite state machine) to do it

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted a regex for each month name and to add a tab use [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
lines = """Yes, I'd say so. Nov 08, 2014 UTC
Hell yes! Oct 01, 2014 UTC
Anbefalt som bare det, løp og kjøp. Sep 16, 2014 UTC"""

r = re.compile(r"\bJan\b|\bFeb\b|\bMar\b|\bApr\b|\bMay\b|\bJun\b|\bJul\b|\bAug\b|\bSep\b|\bOct\b|\bNov\b|\bDec\b")

for line in lines.splitlines():
    print(r.sub("\t"+r"\g<0>", line))
```

Output:

```
Yes, I'd say so.    Nov 08, 2014 UTC
Hell yes!   Oct 01, 2014 UTC
Anbefalt som bare det, løp og kjøp.     Sep 16, 2014 UTC
```

It does not matter what format the lines are in, the regex will still find the exact matches for any month.

To match exactly month spaces digits and a comma:

```
r = re.compile(r"(\bJan\b)\s+\d+,|(\bFeb\b)\s+\d+,|(\bMar\b)\s+\d+,|(\bApr\b)\s+\d+,|"
               r"(\bMay\b)\s+\d+,|(\bJun\b)\d+,|(\bJul\b)\s+\d+,|(\bAug\b)\s+\d+,|"
               r"(\bSep\b)\s+\d+,|(\bOct\b)\s+\d+,|(\bNov\b)\s+\d+,|(\bDec\b)\s+\d+,")
```

Answer (score -1):

## Split at 16 characters in from the end

```
data = """Yes, I'd say so. Nov 08, 2014 UTC
Hell yes! Oct 01, 2014 UTC
Anbefalt som bare det, løp og kjøp. Sep 16, 2014 UTC"""
```

You can reformat the dates however you like too.

```
from datetime import datetime
    
fmt = "%b %d, %Y %Z"

for line in data.split("\n"):
    txt = line[:-16]
    dt = datetime.strptime(line[-16:], fmt)
    print("{}\t{}".format(txt, dt.strftime(fmt)))
```

Comment: Any idea why I'm down voted? This answer is correct I think. If the date format is consistent then its a simple split on 16 characters.